# Low E buzz troubleshooting

Tags: guitar, acoustic-guitar, fingerstyle-guitar, buzz

I've got low E string buzz on both my acoustic guitars (Washburn and small bodied Hohner). I'm using light gauge strings mostly in standard but occasionally open tunings.

The buzz is mostly noticeable when I strum or pick hard. Is it worth getting them both professionally setup or would you just switch string gauge? I do quite like playing with lights, especially for fingerstyle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If both guitars buzz with light strings but not with heavier strings, then there are a couple of options. I'm assuming the buzz is happening when the string touches a fret somewhere near the middle of its vibrating length; if the buzz is at the nut or bridge or somewhere else, then this line of thinking does not apply.

You could switch to a heavier gauge, or a set with light-tops/heavy-bottoms. Or, you may be able to use your desired set if you raise the action on the bass strings. Bridge-adjustments vary with the style of bridge, but on most recent acoustics I've seen the bridge is a removable piece of bone or plastic. (**Do not do this yourself with a piezo pickup system, you may affect the balance of the pickup signal.**) To raise this type of bridge, you

- slacken (or remove) all the strings,
- remove the bridge piece,
- add 1 or 2 paper *shims* into the cavity where the bridge piece goes,
- replace bridge piece,
- tune-up and evaluate (are we done or does it need another few shims?)

Comment: If it's an electro-acoustic, with a piezzo bridge, would pieces of paper affect the pick up's propensity to pick up?

Comment: Indeed, [This article](http://www.guitar-hospital.net/tips-and-tricks/stringing-acoustic-piezo-electric-guitar) suggests this procedure may lead to problems with a piezo system.

Comment: It *might* be worth looking at the [truss rod](http://www.fretnotguitarrepair.com/repair/acoustic-guitar/truss-rod.php) as well. Sometimes it needs adjustment when changing string gauges. Be careful though, this can damage the guitar if done improperly.