# D string buzzes when I play a chord, but not when I play the string alone

Tags: classical-guitar, buzz

When I play chords, the "D" String buzzes really loudly, but when I play it alone, it doesn't. (Doesn't matter if I pressed the fret or not).

Comment: Guitarbeginner - you need to ask single questions here. Kevin and amalgamate have provided excellent answers, but you need to ask single questions - which also helps the system identify duplicates, eg for 3 we have http://music.stackexchange.com/q/24392/104 and there are multiple questions covering 1, so I'll remove them from your question and just leave your question on the D string buzz.

Comment: Thank all of you for your answers, they really helped me a lot :D. I'm still struggling with positioning my left hand fast so it wouldn't touch the e string, and pressing the string against the fret 100% hurts a little, but the answers helped me a lot :D. Also thanks admin, if I'll get multiple questions I will know what to do :D.

Answer (score 4):

The buzzing is due to the string rattling against one of the frets. You need to press down with your finger on the D string directly behind the fret.  Your finger is too far from the fret so the string is rattling against it.

Answer (score 2):

@Kevin Johnsrude is correct, but I will add to his list here:

4. It is possible for a guitar to have problems with buzzing that are not caused by the guitarist. The action may be too low. The frets may be too warn. The neck may be warped.
5. Also placing your finger on the string is an art. The target area on your fingers that produces good tone is smaller than that which merely touches the string to the fret.
6. Sometimes strings can buzz against your finger nails of other fingers on other strings, but you will feel/ notice this most of the time.
7. Long fingernails on your left hand can also get in the way of proper finger placement (relevant to 5 and 1)

Practice can help improve the accuracy of your finger.

A good guitar teacher would better diagnose your issues, which are likely to be more than one of those listed.

Arch, btw, is the curve of your finger. The more curved your finger is, the more muscle strength you are using (to a degree) and also the more your fingers can select which string(s) they are touching.

You can also add strength to your fingering by pulling back with your entire arm. Avoid gripping too tightly with your thumb, as that can slow you down.

Comment: Note that @Dr Mayhem removed most of the relevance of my answer from the OP.